# Efeito de Zoom em DIV

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, zoom

Preciso fazer um efeito igual a essa página http://www.kanui.com.br/roupas-femininas/blusas/ .

Quando passar o mouse sobre o produto (DIV) ele da um efeito de zoom e levantada.

Tentei fazer assim:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-3 classe">

<img src="imagem.jpg" class="img-responsive">

<!-- INFORMAÇÕES -->
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.classe:hover{
text-shadow: .....
}
```

Coloquei pra colocar uma sombra como na página mas não adiantou, ficou "grotesco". Precisava do mesmo efeito que a página. Como poderia fazer ?

Comment: Não notei o efeito zoom, apenas o efeito de 'levantada" e sobra, isto é feito com ajuste de posicionamento mais um box-shadow, vou tentar formular uma resposta.

Comment: de uma olhada nesse fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/27Syr/1206/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não notei nenhum zoom, apenas a "levantada" que na verdade é o box-shadow que causa esta impressão, são necessários algumas coisas:

- `box-shadow` pra causar o efeito de destacar da página ou sobrepor
- `position: relative;` para que o elemento interno que usa position: absolute; não saia da área
- Eu poderia ter usado a propriedade `zoom`, mas aplicar um simples width no elemento com :hover já faz o efeito
- A imagem esta em com `display: block` pra evitar o `line-height` afetar os elementos, `margin: 0 auto;` alinha elementos block no centro.

Eu preferi usar o `position: absolute;` pois apenas com relative ou margens negativas poderiam afetar os elementos a volta.

Em um exemplo rápido seria isto:

```css
div.item {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 400px;
}

div.item div.inner {
    border: 1px transparent solid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

div.item div.inner:hover {
    border-color: #a5a5a5;
    box-shadow: 8px 7px 0 -3px rgba(55,55,55,0.2);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 110%; /*ajusta a largura do zoom*/
}

div.item div.inner img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW1Bu.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Você também pode usar transition pra causar um efeito suave, assim:

```css
div.item {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 400px;
}

div.item div.inner {
    border: 1px transparent solid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all .2s;
}

div.item div.inner:hover {
    border-color: #a5a5a5;
    box-shadow: 8px 7px 0 -3px rgba(55,55,55,0.2);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 110%; /*ajusta a largura do zoom*/
}

div.item div.inner img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW1Bu.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: acho que esse "zoom" é tipo a imagem que da uma aumentada, veja se estou certo e como poderia fazer isso. O código acima já me ajuda, agora só falta essa aumentada na imagem

Comment: @AlissonAcioli sim parece que aumenta, mas na verdade é o `width: 100%;`, vou editar o exemplo.

Comment: @AlissonAcioli pronto editei o exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme! Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, valeu!

Comment: @AlissonAcioli viu a diferença do transition e sem transition, achei que ficaria legal =D

Comment: Sim, com trasition é melhor, tira esse "seco" do efeito.